# Best method to locate object with opencv

Tags: python, object, opencv, location

What is the most efficient way using opencv and python to locate and return the coordinates of a single object that has a constant color? I have seen a few ways to do so using c++, but info on object location using python is sparse.

Comment: Why not port over the C++ code to python yourself?

Comment: Is the question about which OpenCV call to use, or how to get access to the C++ calls you like in Python?

Comment: For future use, how would I port the c++ code to python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking for exactly, but I think you should have a look at the [Haar classification](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection).

See here for example:
http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs4411/wiki/index.php?title=OpenCV_Guide#Haar_Classifier

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific if you have an object with single colour you can look at the camshift tracker. The [camshift demo](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/python/camshift.py?rev=2136) in Python is included with the OpenCV source. It is much more efficient for a single colour blob than Haar and requires virtually no training, just initialization with where the object is.